# PostgreSQL Select INTO with CASE statement

Tags: postgresql

I have an Employee table with column - **Id, FirstName, isGlobal, Age**. I am writing below SQL to check if the Employee already exists in DB or not. I want to store the Id and isGlobal into variable for further processing in my stored function.

```
SELECT Id, CASE WHEN (isGlobal IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        INTO o_NameId, o_IsGlobal
        FROM Employee  
        WHERE firstName='test';
```

On running this SQL, it gives me syntax error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 2:         INTO o_NameId, o_IsGlobal 
                             ^
SQL state: 42601
```

What's wrong with my SQL?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use variables outside of a PL/pgSQL function or block

Answer (score 0):

looks like o_NameId and o_IsGlobal are not declared, 
try:

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        o_NameId int;
        o_IsGlobal int;
    BEGIN
        SELECT Id, CASE WHEN (isGlobal IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        INTO o_NameId, o_IsGlobal
        FROM Employee
        WHERE firstName='test';

    END
$$;
```

also try to follow SQL name convention like:

- SQL keywords: UPPER CASE
- names (identifiers) lower_case_with_underscores List item